# How to make expand and collapse manually child wise in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, accordion

I have an accordion expand is working fine but collapse is not working,it should work like accordion,for ex when I click 'title 2' its content should expand and 'title 1' content should collapse.below is my code,I am new to angularjs.Anyone can help me.If its in jquery also fine.

### HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>   
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="item=1"><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="item==1">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

### index.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',

      isOpen: true,
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a']
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',

      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',

    }
  ];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you those functions :

```
  $scope.open = function (index) {
    $scope.groups[index].isOpen = !$scope.groups[index].isOpen;
    $scope.closeOthers(index);
  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (index) {
    for(var i = 0; i  < $scope.groups.length; i++) {
       if (i !== index)
        $scope.groups[i].isOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

`open` is fired when clicking on a parent, `closeOthers` is called in `open`. I init a `visible` boolean to parents. Each time user clicks on a parent, it set `visible` to `true`, and others to `false`.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups track by $index">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open($index)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[Working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/nCdGzZYPSTYsMPYf8K9o?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer is it possible to interchange the '+' icon and '-' icon at the time of expand and collapse

Comment: Yes sure, you have to add an `ngClass` directive on your icon, and watch _isOpen_ value. Edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.is it possible to do without using group or groups which is coming from ng repeat

Comment: You can't. `isOpen` is an attribute from `group`